# Java Callable : What happens to the thread before get() is called

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, callable

More precisely : If I start async computation by calling `submit(Callable<T> task)` method on an `ExecutorService` (itself constructed with `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`), I can wait for the computation to finish and retrieve the result by calling `Future.get()`.

My question is : if the computation is already finished, what happens until I call `get()`? Does the thread is blocked until I retrieved the result? Does the result is stored and the thread assigned to another task? Something completely different?

Thanks in advance for you answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Thread is not blocked, it is returned to the pool.
In general it is the `get()` calling thread dependant on worker, not the other way around. So if there is a result, return it, if not, wait until it will be available.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Just to be sure I understand you correctly (sorry, English is not my mother tongue) : If I launch several threads for computations and retrieve the result only much later when all are finished, it's not a problem because finished tasks doesn't use any resources, right?

Comment: @shadow_heart The result of the computation (=task) is stored within the `Future` object, so you can `get()` it whenever you want. `get()` only blocks the calling thread in case the computation has not finished yet.